# signals fire up at every user login instead of post_save

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a small signal connected to post_save of the user model. I want it to only send an email on user creation and not on login as it does in this form.

I've tried with if created: but still sends email on login.

from django.db.models.signals import post_save

```
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

        print("Signal patched")
        subject = 'New Order Created %s'%instance
        message = 'Order %s created at %s . Please check if needs further settings!'%(instance, datetime.now())
        emailFrom = 'test@test.com'
        emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        send_mail(subject, message, emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=True)




post_save.connect(save_profile, sender=Order)
```

Comment: can you update your question with the `Order` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger it only if it's created.

```
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print("Signal patched")
        subject = 'New Order Created %s'%instance
        message = 'Order %s created at %s . Please check if needs further settings!'%(instance, datetime.now())
        emailFrom = 'test@test.com'
        emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        send_mail(subject, message, emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=True)
```

And it seems that it's connected to `Order` not to user:

`post_save.connect(save_profile, sender=User)`

Comment: Yup, I was doing the same for the order and messed up the paste. Thank you, that is the answer. Tested and it works.